# Почему не работает onMouseLeave в react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Не работает onMouseLeave когда кнопка `disabled`, а когда `enabled` то работает

```
class Save extends Component {
state = {
    tooltipShow: false
}

tooltipOpen () {
    this.setState({
        tooltipShow: true
    });
}

tooltipClose (){
    this.setState({
        tooltipShow: false
    });
}

render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="test" onMouseEnter={this.tooltipOpen.bind(this)} onMouseLeave={this.tooltipClose.bind(this)}>
               <button disabled>Click</button>
            </div>
            {
                this.state.tooltipShow 
                && <InfoTooltip text={i18next.t("tooltip.not-playing")} button="hidden" width="198px"/>
            }
        </div>
    );
}}
```

Comment: События мыши не работают на отключенных нативных элементах браузера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это баг. Попробуйте добавить в CSS стили:

```
button[disabled] {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное помогло